Transaction Management with React / SQL Server not working as expected
In the following code I initiate a transaction, commit (supposedly on success) and rollback (allegedly) on error. To test the transaction, with my debugger, I deliberately end processing on the line before commit. I notice, however, that after aborting processing before commit, the registrant and token tables are still populated with new inserted data. What am I missing?
export const addRegistrant = async (req, res) => {
    let transaction;
    try {
        // The following in completed within the context of
        const pool = await poolPromise;
        transaction = new sql.Transaction(pool, { isolationLevel: sql.ISOLATION_LEVEL.READ_COMMITTED, autocommit: false });

        // Begin the transaction
        await transaction.begin();

        const registrant = await registrantService.addRegistrant(req.body, transaction);
        const token = await registrantService.createVerificationTokenForNewRegistrant(registrant, transaction);
        await registrantService.sendVerificationEmail(req, registrant, req.body.origin, token, transaction);

        // Commit the transaction if everything goes well
        await transaction.commit();

        res.status(201).json(registrant);
    } catch (err) {
        // If any error occurs, roll back the transaction
        if (transaction) await transaction.rollback();

        console.log(err.message);
        let message;
        switch (err.number) {
            case 2601:
            case 2627:
                message = "Your email is already used in Swift! Try login";
                break;
            default:
                message = err.message;
        }
        res.status(500).send(message);
    }
};

FYI, here is "addRegistrant" from registrantService:
async addRegistrant(registrant) {
    const pool = await poolPromise;

    // Generate salt and hash password
    const salt = generateSalt();
    const hash = await hashPassword(registrant.password, salt);

    const result = await pool.request()
            .input('email', sql.VarChar, registrant.email)
            .input('salt', sql.VarChar, salt)
            .input('password', sql.VarChar, hash)
            .input('lastName', sql.VarChar, registrant.lastName)
            .input('firstName', sql.VarChar, registrant.firstName)
            .input('middleInitial', sql.VarChar, registrant.middleInitial)
            .input('dateOfBirth', sql.Date, registrant.dateOfBirth)
            .query('INSERT INTO Registrant_Physical (email, salt, password, lastName, firstName, dateOfBirth) OUTPUT INSERTED.* VALUES (@email, @salt, @password, @lastName, @firstName, @dateOfBirth)');

    return result.recordset[0];
}

At the behest of ChatGPT, which suggested the my aborting processing does not allow the rollback to be executed (makes sense). So, I added the following before commit:
    // Simulate error before commit
    throw new Error("Simulating failure before commit");

    // Commit the transaction if everything goes well
    await transaction.commit();

Nothing changed. The tables are still populated with new data although the transaction was rolled back.

Wouldn't await pool.request() generate a new connection, so whatever you're doing with the transaction won't affect it?

It is redundant since i am now using await new sql.Request(transaction)

The problem and consequently the solution are both simple:

I neglected to pass "transaction" to my service
I had to create a new Request(transaction) for each DB command

Having done the above, the abort and simulate error works as I had expected.
Here are the revised methods:
async addRegistrant(registrant, transaction) {
        const pool = await poolPromise;

        // Generate salt and hash password
        const salt = generateSalt();
        const hash = await hashPassword(registrant.password, salt);

        const result = await new sql.Request(transaction)
            .input('email', sql.VarChar, registrant.email)
            .input('salt', sql.VarChar, salt)
            .input('password', sql.VarChar, hash)
            .input('lastName', sql.VarChar, registrant.lastName)
            .input('firstName', sql.VarChar, registrant.firstName)
            .input('middleInitial', sql.VarChar, registrant.middleInitial)
            .input('dateOfBirth', sql.Date, registrant.dateOfBirth)
            .query('INSERT INTO Registrant_Physical (email, salt, password, lastName, firstName, dateOfBirth) OUTPUT INSERTED.* VALUES (@email, @salt, @password, @lastName, @firstName, @dateOfBirth)');

        return result.recordset[0];
    }

    async createVerificationTokenForNewRegistrant(registrant, transaction) {
        const token = crypto.randomBytes(64).toString('hex');

        const pool = await poolPromise;
        await new sql.Request(transaction)
            .input('registrantId', sql.Int, registrant.registrantId)
            .input('token', sql.NVarChar, token)
            .query(`INSERT INTO EmailVerificationToken (registrantId, token) VALUES (@registrantId, @token)`);

        return token;
    }

